# Reload Magento frontend notification messages

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm adding items to basket in Magento through my external JavaScript widget.  I'm also updating Minicart by calling reloadMiniCart() function in my widget:

```
    <script>
    function reloadMiniCart() {
    require([
    'jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($, cd) {
        cd.reload(['cart'], true);
    });

    }
    </script>
```

It works and Minicart is updating but I'm facing an issue that message `You added XXX to your shopping cart.` is showing AFTER I refresh a page. How should I refresh notification messages? Adding `cd.reload('messages');` seems to not work

Answer (score 0):

Try also reloading the messages customer data section like this :

```
<script>
  function reloadMiniCart() {
  require([
 'jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($, cd) {
    cd.reload(['cart'], true);
    cd.reload(['messages'], true);
});

}
</script>
```